# How could I make the changes in `usr/include/linux/binfmts.h` file make effect?

Tags: linux, compiling, make, binfmt

I have Ubuntu server that is running Linux 4.15.0-1082-azure. 
I updated the `usr/include/linux/binfmts.h` file in order to increase the size of argument list. I changed the `MAX_ARG_PAGES`.

I need to recompile, install and reboot into the new kernel so the changes takes effect , but I do not know how to do that.

I tried these following command,

```
make
make modules_install
make install
reboot
```

but I got error messages when run make commands:

```
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
***
*** Configuration file ".config" not found!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:37: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
Makefile:573: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:253: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

I tried to use make menuconfig , but I cannot understand it I was worried to breakdown something on the server.

How could I make the changes in `usr/include/linux/binfmts.h` file make effect?
How could I know if the new setting is taking the effect or not?

Comment: Not really related to your current issue, but what was the issue with `MAX_ARG_PAGES` being too small? There are usually ways to work around that limitation, and reconfiguring the _kernel_ to support long argument lists seems to be a slightly awkward way to "solve" it.

Comment: I have scripts that call psql command , but when I pass long query to psql, I got this error message `/usr/bin/psql: Argument list too long`. I used this command ` ulimit -S -s unlimited` to increase the MAX_ARG, however it is not working still getting the error.